# Use two UITextView with instance Method "textView(_:shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText:)"

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitextview, func

I have two UITextView in a ViewController and I want to limit the number of characters the user can edit in the TextView. 
I'm using the Method    `textView(_:shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText:)`

The protocol `UITextViewDelegate` is declared

Both UITextView have an outlet

`@IBOutlet weak var UITextView1: UITextView!
 @IBOutlet weak var UITextView2: UITextView!`

and a delegation

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UITextView1.delegate = self
    UITextView2.delegate = self
}
```

I have tried different ways to make it work for both UITextView (use function twice or switch statement to adjust parameters)

Actually my code below pass the build test with no error.

```
 // maximise number of characters typed in UITextViews
func textView( _ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {


    if let UITextViewA = UITextView1 {

            let TextView1MaxLengh = 10
            let TextView1Num = (UITextViewA.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
            let numberOfChars = TextView1Num.count
            let NumberCharsString = "- \(String(TextView1MaxLengh - numberOfChars)) -"

            return numberOfChars < TextView1MaxLengh     
    }


   if let UITextViewB = UITextView2 {

            let TextView2MaxLengh = 20
            let TextView2Num = (UITextViewB.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
            let numberOfChars2 = TextView2Num.count
            let NumberCharsString2 = "- \(String(TextView2MaxLengh - numberOfChars2)) -"

            return numberOfChars2 < TextView2MaxLengh     
    }
        return true
    }
```

When I run the app and edit the TextView1 it work perfectly, but when I try to edit the second one the app crash with following message :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: Range or index out of bounds'
```

I'm pretty sure it is related to a delegation aspect but can't get through it

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The `textView` passed into the delegate method is the one being changed. Try `if textView == UITextView1`. Also, you shouldn't Capitalize your variables.

Comment: Thanks Don for your fast answer!  You were right.  It work perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help.